# Error in inserting data from React Native (Android App) to MySql Database

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to Insert my Form Data from React Native CLI (Android App) to MySQL database but when I press Submit, it always shows a message: "An error has occurred: Network request failed".
There is an API named as form_insert.php which is meant to insert all the fields of the FormData from React native CLI to mySQL database.
I have tried different combinations of code but everytime error occurs.
Moreover, I tested my API in PostMan tool and the API is working perfectly but with the combination of code snippet of react native app, I am Encountering errors.
Below will be given the Code Snippet of React Native CLI along with the API code.

Code Snippet of React Native CLI Where the API is called:

```
const handleFormSubmit = async () => {
if (
customerName &&
customerNumber &&
carModel &&
carNumber &&
selectedOption &&
selectedOption2 &&
selectedOption3
) {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('cusCode', customerCode);
formData.append('cusName', customerName);
formData.append('cusNum', customerNumber);
formData.append('carModel', carModel);
formData.append('carNum', carNumber);
formData.append('carBrand', selectedOption);
formData.append('engineType', selectedOption2);
formData.append('vehType', selectedOption3);
formData.append('lubeName', lubeName);
formData.append('lubeLtr', lubeNumber);
formData.append('dateTime', new Date().toString());

  
try {
const response = await fetch('https://10.0.2.2:80/api/form_insert.php', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // Update the content type
},
body: new URLSearchParams(formData), // Use URLSearchParams to format the form data
});

if (response.ok) {
alert('Data inserted successfully');
console.log(await response.json());
} else {
throw new Error('An error occurred during the request');
}
} 
catch (error) {
console.error(error);
alert('An error occurred: ' + error.message);
}

onSubmit(formData);
}
};
```

API code:

```
<?php
// Allow requests from any origin
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
// Allow specific HTTP methods
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
// Allow specific headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'pso_app';

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Retrieve data from the form
$customerCode = isset($_POST['cusCode']) ? $_POST['cusCode'] : null;
$customerName = isset($_POST['cusName']) ? $_POST['cusName'] : null;
$customerNumber = isset($_POST['cusNum']) ? $_POST['cusNum'] : null;
$carModel = isset($_POST['carModel']) ? $_POST['carModel'] : null;
$carNumber = isset($_POST['carNum']) ? $_POST['carNum'] : null;
$carBrand = isset($_POST['carBrand']) ? $_POST['carBrand'] : null;
$engineType = isset($_POST['engineType']) ? $_POST['engineType'] : null;
$vehicleType = isset($_POST['vehType']) ? $_POST['vehType'] : null;
$lubeName = isset($_POST['lubeName']) ? $_POST['lubeName'] : null;
$lubeNumber = isset($_POST['lubeLtr']) ? $_POST['lubeLtr'] : null;
$dateTime = isset($_POST['dateTime']) ? $_POST['dateTime'] : null;

// Prepare and bind the INSERT statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO lube_sale (cus_code, cus_name, cus_num, car_model, car_num,     car_brand,     

engine_type, veh_type, lube_name, lube_ltr, date_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $customerCode, $customerName, $customerNumber, $carModel, $carNumber,                
$carBrand, $engineType, $vehicleType, $lubeName, $lubeNumber, $dateTime);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

// Close the statement
$stmt->close();

// Close the database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```